# Subject Verb Agreement with the word "every"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

> Every Bentley, Lamborghini, and Porsche (is/are) owned by Volkswagen

I had some difficulties with this because I thought that the answer would have to be "are" because 
a) There are different objects that are being listed out

b)"every" signifies multiple things so I thought that it would entail that I ought to choose "are"

But the answer key dictates that the answer is "is" and I don't understand why that is.

I was wondering if it has to do anything with the word "every"?

Comment: _Every_, as well as _each_, is used to single out the subjects and always takes a singular verb. See: http://uwf.edu/writinglabapp/minilessons/mini-lesson_15x.htm, and http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/every

Comment: Incidentally, that sentence means that Volkswagen owns every individual car of those three brands.  The intended meaning might be different, for example that Volkswagen owns the three named companies or trademarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every refers to *each concrete example* of the listed items as individuals -- that is, ***every Bentley is [X]*** is sort of a shorthand way of saying ***your Bentley, my Bentley is [X], my other Bentley is [X], and my wife's Bentley is [X].***  So it is referring to a bunch of singular items discretely.  As such, the collection takes a singular verb -- *is* in your example:

> Every Bentley, Lamborghini, and Porsche **is** owned by Volkswagen.

This also applies to words such as *each* and *either*.  See [this link](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/SubjectVerb.html#each) for more info.

Updated to fix a real brain fart on my part.

Comment: 'Your Bentley, my Bentley, my other Bentley, [and] my wife's Bentley...' takes plural agreement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth -- You're right...  Today must be my stupid day.  Again.  I'll fix it.